# Extra database server in farm

Tags: database, sql-server

Recently I was looking at Central Admin > Operations > Servers in Farm and noticed an extra database server. It is the same name as the actual database server with "-Common" appended to the end. This is a machine that doesn't exist on my network. I don't know if it hurts anything, but it really bothers me.

I really want to click "Remove Server", but I'm worried it may remove the actual server. has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be ok to remove it as long is it isnt inactual use.

The server may not be removed by just clicking the remove server button. Sometimes you will need to use stsadm -o deleteconfigurationobject instead

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen that before.  I would check to make sure none of the content databases show that path and if everything is clear, I would think it is safe to remove the server.